# How are file/directory paths inferred from within an executable in windows?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When we specify the path to a file or an executable in C++ source code how does it get resolved when the object files for the source code is packaged into an executable?

For example if I were to use [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=vs-2017) in my program and wanted to run another executable how would I provide the path to that executable.

Here's what I tried:

1. Put the external executable in the same directory as the source
   code: works as expected in debug mode within visual studio.
2. Put the external executable inside the Debug / Release directory of
   the project, then the executable which I am building will not see
   the external executable I am trying to invoke using `_popen`.

In java world, I could infer a jar file as another file system and I could read the paths just like how I would do on any other file system.

Sorry if the question is a bit crude. I have just jumped into windows application development using visual C++ from being a java/ruby web developer. So I am not even able to come up with the right keywords to search on the internet.

Comment: `_popen()` expects an executable either in the current working directory of your process, a full path, or residing in one of the directories specified in the `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: Maybe you'll find the answer here: [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)

Comment: put it wherever you want and update the PATH env varaible or specify the full path name

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. That was very helpful. So it appears that how the path is inferred depends on what method I use to accomplish the task.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks. I came across CreateProcess(). But I couldn't correctly understand the usage. But from the many posts that I read, I do agree that CreateProcess() is probably the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this compiles, it is close:

```
TCHAR szExePath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(0, szExePath, _countof(szExePath)); // 0 for handle is the process handle shortcut for this API

TCHAR szDrive[MAX_PATH] szDir[MAX_PATH]
_tsplitpath(szExePath, szDrive, szDir, NULL, NULL);

TCHAR szNewExePath;
_tmakepath(szNewExePath, szDrive, szDir, _T("numerodos"), _T(".exe")); // change numerodos do something real

TCHAR flags  = _T("wt"); // or whatever
_popen(szNewExePath, flags);

// really, on Windows I'd probably use CreateProcess
```